# Div's moving and resizing in harmony

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make it so when one div becomes smaller in height the other moves up with it.

Here's a [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/MichaelT/rN6dT/)

So if I was to make `#top` (which has absolute positioning) have a height of 400px instead of 600px, how to I ensure the relatively-positioned div below it moves up to 420px from the top, from it's original position of 620px?

Basically, it's to respond to the browser. If the browser is made smaller, `#top` will scale, so the div below needs to move with it.

UPDATE

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-UK">
    <head>
        <link href="Stylesheet.css" rel ="stylesheet" type="text/css">


        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="top"></div>
        <div id ="logo"></div>
<div class="container">A wiki (i/ˈwɪkiː/ wik-ee) is a website which allows its users to add, modify, or delete its content via a web browser usually using a simplified markup language or a rich-text editor.[1][2][3] Wikis are powered by wiki software. Most are created collaboratively.
Wikis may serve many different purposes, such as knowledge management and notetaking. Wikis can be community websites and intranets, for example. Some permit control over different functions (levels of access). For example, editing rights may permit changing, adding or removing material. Others may permit access without enforcing access control. Other rules may also be imposed for organizing content.
Ward Cunningham, the developer of the first wiki software, WikiWikiWeb, originally described it as "the simplest online database that could possibly work."[4] "Wiki" (pronounced [ˈwiti] or [ˈviti]) is a Hawaiian word meaning "fast" or "quick".[5]A wiki (i/ˈwɪkiː/ wik-ee) is a website which allows its users to add, modify, or delete its content via a web browser usually using a simplified markup language or a rich-text editor.[1][2][3] Wikis are powered by wiki software. Most are created collaboratively.
Wikis may serve many different purposes, such as knowledge management and notetaking. Wikis can be community websites and intranets, for example. Some permit control over different functions (levels of access). For example, editing rights may permit changing, adding or removing material. Others may permit access without enforcing access control. Other rules may also be imposed for organizing content.
Ward Cunningham, the developer of the first wiki software, WikiWikiWeb, originally described it as "the simplest online database that could possibly work</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
}

div#top{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width:100%;
    height: 600px;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background-color: black;
    border-bottom: 3px solid white;
    margin-bottom: 20px;

}


div#logo{
    position:absolute;
    color: green;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}


.container{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 920px;

    }​
```

Padding issue

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you need to keep `#top` as `position: absolute`, there is no CSS-only way of doing this. Since `#top` is absolute, it is no longer part of the document flow, and `#container` can no longer relate to it. You can either

A. Use javascript to watch the `window.resize` event or whichever resizing event you're referring to, then perform math to change the `top` property for `#container`

or

B. Change `#top` to `position: relative` and remove the `top` CSS property from `#container`

or

C. Use percentage-based values for `#top`'s height and `#container`'s `top` property.

Comment: thanks; option b works. However, my top div no longer runs to the edges?

Comment: Change `#container`'s width to 100% or any other percentage < 100

Comment: no, i have a width of 720 set. So adding 100% doesn't work. Why does add spacing to the left and top. I've updated my post with a image and the code

Comment: Ok, well try `html, body {margin: 0; padding: 0}` in your CSS. Aside from that, I've answered your original question. Accept this answer, and if you still have trouble, open another question. You'll get better focused attention that way